# Is two way binding with an attribute expression possible in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I've noticed that two way binding only works when the expression is *only* the variable name itself (e.g., `{{value}}`). The two way binding breaks if the expression needs to act on the value, (e.g., `{{value*5}}`). Is this a limitation in Polymer, are there any workarounds for the use case of many values needing to be derived from an expression?

```
  Clicking the +/- buttons should increment all 3 numbers at the same time.

  <br/>
  <br/>

   <polymer-element name='test-input'>

       <template>

           <style>
               #val {
                   font-size: 50px;
               }
           </style>

           <div id='val'>{{value}}</div>

           <button on-tap='{{increment}}'>+</button>
           <button on-tap='{{decrement}}'>-</button>

       </template>

       <script>
           Polymer({

               publish: {
                   value: 0
               },
               increment: function() {
                   this.value = this.value + 1;
               },
               decrement: function() {
                   this.value = this.value - 1;
               }
           })
       </script>
   </polymer-element>

   <polymer-element name='test-app'>
       <template>
           Hue:
           <b>{{hue}}</b>

           <br/>
           <br/>

           First:

           <test-input id='two' value='{{hue}}'></test-input>
           <br/>
           (this one works)
           <br/>
           <br/>

           Second:
           <test-input id='one' value='{{hue * 5}}'></test-input>
           <br/>
           (this one does not work)


       </template>
       <script>
           Polymer({ 
               hue: 5,
           })
       </script>
   </polymer-element>


   <test-app></test-app>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KjQ9DusaFg2jp1BTFUde?p=preview

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try following the examples in the docs : `Polymer('test-input', 
      ready: function() {
        this.hue = 5;
      }
    });`

Comment: @Anthony Please look at the example before stating the solution is to RTM. Setting a default value is not the issue here.

Comment: No, the issue is that you didn't have the binding wrapped in an on ready event listener.

Comment: @Anthony Again, that is not the problem. Adding `this.hue = 5` in `ready` function does not make the example work, nor does it change the already default value of `hue` since it is already `5`.

Answer (score 1):

Next error, that appears in your Plunk, means wrong order in importing of the elements:

"Attributes on test-input were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element. This may result in incorrect binding types."

Just switch the order of element definitions.

Here is the corrected [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/er1RIxhM0o91WwfmVcMk?p=preview).

```
<body>


           <polymer-element name='test-input' attributes="testData">
           ...
```

EDIT:

Here is one work around the problem. Problem came out to be in using expression in the child element attribute:

```
//1. this is not working
<test-input id='one' value='{{hue * 10}}'></test-input>

//2. this works
<test-input id='one' value='{{hue}}'></test-input>

//3. multiplying is done in the child element using filter:
{{value | myltiply}}
```

Here is the working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/m63YYTScxuG2rkceRWBm?p=preview)

Can't tell why 1. is not working, I would like to know the background of that too.

Comment: You somehow found an old plunk. Correct plunk is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KjQ9DusaFg2jp1BTFUde?p=preview where that error does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demonstration to why Polymer does not update the **property** when **binded** inside a **input value attribute**.

```
<polymer-element name='my-test-element'>
    <template>
        Number: {{num}}<br>
        <input id='one' value='{{num}}' on-keypress='{{keyPressHandler}}' /><br>
        Value: {{$.one.value}}
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            num: 0,
            keyPressHandler: function(){
                this.$.one.value = this.num*4;
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This would cause the same effect. The value inside the **input** would change every time you changed the value. The situation speaks for itself...

Edit:
Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/UEoqBGXAyzROJsP20suU?p=preview

Comment: This doesn't answer my question and isn't even related. Also, you are purposefully creating a loop-back by setting the value again every time it changes.

Comment: I know, but this would have the same effect on a **input** element! I believe that the reason Polymer does not update your _databinding with expressions_ is because this might occur. So we have a listener on a DOM value. When that value changes we multiply it by 4 and send it back to the DOM. Wops! DOM just recognized a change - loop. I have no other answer to provide you with.